# Cuda Compute Capability

Tags: cuda

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста будет ли работать программа скомпилирована на машине с видеокартой с compute capability 5.0 на машине с видеокартой с compute capability 5.2?

Answer (score 1):

При компиляции можно указывать любую архитектуру. Для компиляции так же не требуется наличие видеокарты.

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/maxwell-compatibility-guide/

Если добавить `-gencode=arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=compute_52` в параметрах компилятора, то ptx код будет скомпилирован и для 5.2 СС карт.